# Display value of the checked checkboxes in a grid in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having a problem with my group-box. In the group-box i have a grid and in that i have about 20 check-boxes.
The problem is that i need to display value of all the checked check-boxes from the above into another group-box.

I am working in WPF C#.

Which is the event to trigger for the above?

And if the checked check-box is unchecked, the value displayed in 2nd group-box should disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Wpf you have a [Checked Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.checked.aspx), [UnChecked Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.unchecked%28v=vs.100%29) and [Indeterminate Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.indeterminate%28v=vs.100%29) they all use the Generic `RoutedEventHandler` so you should be able to wire them up with a Common Event Handler, check the Senders Name or a Unique Indentifier in the `Tag` Property and use that to change your Value in the other `GroupBox`.

**Xaml**

```
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Checked="checkedChanged" Unchecked="checkedChanged" Indeterminate="checkedChanged" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="checkBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tag="1" />
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Checked="checkedChanged" Unchecked="checkedChanged" Indeterminate="checkedChanged" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,36,0,0" Name="checkBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tag="2" />
```

**Xaml.cs**

```
private void checkedChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
    int index;
    if (int.TryParse(cb.Tag.ToString(), out index))
    {
        if (cb.IsChecked == true)
        {
            switch (index)
            {
                case 1:
                    break;

                case 2:
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (cb.IsChecked == false)
        {
            switch (index)
            {
                case 1:
                    break;

                case 2:
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            switch (index)
            {
                case 1:
                    break;

                case 2:
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Example of what I mentioned in my Comments:

**Xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GroupBox Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
            <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="CheckBox" Checked="checkedChanged" Unchecked="checkedChanged" Indeterminate="checkedChanged" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   Name="checkBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tag="0" />
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="CheckBox" Checked="checkedChanged" Unchecked="checkedChanged" Indeterminate="checkedChanged" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   Name="checkBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tag="1" />
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="CheckBox" Checked="checkedChanged" Unchecked="checkedChanged" Indeterminate="checkedChanged" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   Name="checkBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tag="2" />
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="CheckBox" Checked="checkedChanged" Unchecked="checkedChanged" Indeterminate="checkedChanged" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   Name="checkBox4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tag="3" />
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tag="1" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tag="2" />
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tag="3" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tag="4" />
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Xaml.cs**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Label[] myLabels = new Label[4];

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            myLabels[0]=label1;
            myLabels[1]=label2;
            myLabels[2]=label3;
            myLabels[3]=label4;

        }

        private void checkedChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
            int index;
            if (int.TryParse(cb.Tag.ToString(), out index))
            {
                if (cb.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    myLabels[index].Content="Checked";
                }
                else if (cb.IsChecked == false)
                {
                    myLabels[index].Content="UnChecked";
                }
                else
                {
                    myLabels[index].Content="?";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @KaMaLMoHaN Something like above should work for you, it is a little hard to be more specific without seeing your code and it is likely to get more than a little Cumbersome with 20 controls. I probably would make a Array of the objects you are wanting to change and then access them using the Tag as the index, it would greatly reduce the code you would have to write.

Comment: @KaMaLMoHaN to answer your question. In the first If statement I am checking to make sure that I can change string from the Tag property to an Integer, if I can't I am bypassing the logic, the TryParse Method returns true if the conversion can be done and returns the converted value in the index variable.

Comment: I am sorry i didn't understand that part.
About the array part.

Comment: @KaMaLMoHaN What type of Control are you updating in the second panel?

Comment: I am confused with that part also. I haven't added any controls there.
I just created a Group-box and inside that there is a grid.

Comment: @KaMaLMoHaN How are you displaying the values in the Second GroupBox, is it a Label a TextBlock another CheckBox?

Comment: @KaMaLMoHaN I guess I am saying I am confused about what you are wanting to change/update when the CheckBox changes

Comment: I am sorry but that's what i mentioned earlier. I haven't added any.
I was looking for the best possible way. According to your opinion what is the best way to display. Because if checked it should be displayed and if unchecked it should vanish..

Comment: If possible can we have a window sharing option? so that you can see what is actually happening.

Comment: @KaMaLMoHaN give me a few minutes to see if I can come up with a example of what I am talking about.

Comment: Can we add labels at run time to the second group-box, if item checked in the first group-box? How is it possible?

Comment: Thanks Mark for the example. I appreciate your work. I am working on the above mentioned code. But my boss needs 5 more check-boxes,
it means i currently have 25 check-boxes in the first Group-box.
Is it possible to add label while checking the check-box. is that possible?

Comment: @KaMaLMoHaN In my mind it would be easier to create all of the Labels at design time and create the array when the Form Loads, that way you are not incuring the overhead of adding/removing the controls to/from the proper Container object.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I have tried it and it is working. I am innovating the same. Is it possible if i only selects the 4th check-box, it should only be displayed and at the top. I assume you got what i meant.